# Count rows with higher bid than current offer Linq to SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework

In the following table, idea is to count each bid with higher bids having the status 1,

```
id  rate    cur Request Sold    request at  status
1   13  USD 400 0   2016-12-08 11:28:01 1
2   13  USD 400 0   2016-12-08 11:29:01 1
3   12  USD 400 0   2016-12-08 11:29:01 1
4   12  USD 400 0   2016-12-08 11:31:01 1
5   10  USD 400 0   2016-12-08 11:31:01 1
                        
        new     1           
        sold    2
```

this is the query I run for:

```
  int selectedBid = 5;
  decimal selectedBidOfer = 10;
  int higherbid = db.bids.Where(a=>a.StatusId == 1 &&
                                   a.bidId != selectedBid &&
                                   a.bidOffer>= selectedBidOfer ).Count();

  return Content(higherbid.ToString());
```

this will be the result in each change:

if

> int selectedBid = 5; decimal selectedBidOfer = 10;  result will be 4,
> which is correct
>
> int selectedBid = 4; decimal selectedBidOfer = 12;  result will be 3,
> which is correct
>
> int selectedBid = 3; decimal selectedBidOfer = 12;  result will be 3,
> which is not correct, it should result 2 only upper value

Note: here the bidId may not be in order so I could check based on that and time is also not in order means one can give high rate at end and ....

so how will I be able find out the higher bid with status 1, in the explained case?

Comment: Not clear what your saying. The 2nd query will return 2, not 3 (there are only 2 items in your table values greater than 12. And the 3rd query is will return exactly the same as the 2nd query (I'm assuming by `bidOffer` you mean the value in the 2nd column which is named `rate`)

Comment: Then the 3rd query WILL return 3 which is correct- there a 4 records greater than or equal to 12, but you exclude the current one which leaves 3 (not 2). And perhaps you should update you 'table' to show the correct field names.

Comment: it's doing correct, here I will announce amount and there will be bidding and I will sell only high offers until the announce amount, it's like I have announced 500 and there 10 person requesting 100 of the amount each, while 2 first rate is 13 and 5 othere is 12 and 3 is 10 so how I should find to whom system should sell the amount

Comment: @StephenMuecke, if you have for chat, your minute will save lot's of my time

Comment: Sorry, not clear what your saying. You need to edit your question to explain it - not in comments (and update your table to show the actual fields - its all too confusing when you keep referring to different names all the time)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130092/discussion-between-hamza-rafiq-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct, you stated that:

**"int selectedBid = 3; decimal selectedBidOfer = 12; result will be 3, which is not correct, it should result 2 only upper value"**

Your statement "which is not correct" is false, the query is correct in returning a count of 3 because you have a bid = 12 in your database with bidId != 3, if you want the result count to be 2 when int selectedBid = 3; decimal selectedBidOfer = 12 then this is the query you must use

```
  int higherbid = db.bids.Where(a=>a.StatusId == 1 &&
                                   a.bidId != selectedBid &&
                                   a.bidOffer > selectedBidOfer ).Count();
```

The change is instead of a.bidOffer greater than OR EQUALS selectedBidOfer, which is what your query is, my query is: a.bidOffer greater than selectedBidOfer

Comment: @Braun Ogden , yes your answer is correct but my situation is different if you see the row #4 you will find out row #3 is with same offer so there will be problem, here I want if I click the #4 it should show me #3 and if I click #3 should list me 2